# Why does my phone vibrate when service is lost?

Tags: notifications, vibration

My phone (Huawei x1) has started vibrating whenever I lose service and is really annoying. Does anyone know of anyway to fix this? Or maybe there is a setting I accidentally changed to allow this

Answer (score 2):

My Droid Bionic (running Android 2.3.4) has a "network lost tone" setting under Settings/Sounds.   If you the phone is in silent mode with vibrate enabled, this setting might cause a vibrate, although I have not experienced that particular scenario.   Your phone probably has a similar setting.